# How to retrieve the two database colum values to textbox as comma seperated string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i have two textboxes textbox1 & textbox2 and button1 in my ASP.NET and SQL Server database

Database records are:

```
ID         Date               Seats
1          15-Dec-2010        1,2   
2          15-Dec-2010        3,4
3          17-Dec-2010        1,2,3,4
```

I want when i type 15-Dec-2010 in TextBox1 and Click on Button1 then in textbox2 The Output would be retrieve from Database using SELECT query then in TextBox2 the output would be displayed as 1,2,3,4

That the exact i want using SELECT query and VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use a [Calendar-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28VS.80%29.aspx) .You should use ASP.Net CompareValidator for validation. You should check both on client- and serverside to avoid exceptions:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid Date!" EnableClientScript="true" ></asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:Button ID="BtnGetSeats" runat="server" Text="get seats" />
```

On the serverside you should also trigger the validation(f.e. if javascript is disabled).
**To answer your actual question** (untested):

```
Private Sub BtnGetSeats_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnGetSeats.Click
     Page.Validate()
     If Me.IsValid Then
         Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
         Dim commandText As String = "SELECT Seats FROM Table1 WHERE [Date] = @Date"
         Dim allSeats As New List(Of String)
         Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Try
               Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date.Parse(Me.Textbox1.Text))
               connection.Open()
               Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                  While reader.Read
                    Dim nextSeats As String = Convert.ToString(reader(0))
                    allSeats.AddRange(nextSeats.Split(","c))
                  End While
               End Using
           Catch ex As Exception
              Throw 'you should log exceptions'
           End Try
        End Using
        'list all seats comma separated in TextBox2'
        TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", allSeats.ToArray)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use JavaScript  to populate the text in the textbox
2. Submit the form to the server
3. When the result from the server returned show the result